# Trouble installing Ubuntu 14.04 Asus Zenbook NX500J with Nvidia gtx850m

Tags: 14.04, boot, drivers, nvidia

I am trying to install Ubuntu and I can get it to boot off the live usb and install if I set the grub option nomodeset. Once it is installed I am trying to install the Nvidia drivers so I don't have to have nomodeset in the grub boot options and so that I can take advantage of the card. However, when I install the drivers nomodeset is still required and I can no longer login using the GUI. I can get to tty and login normally. I have tried the drivers in the Additional Drivers option and the latest .run file from Nvidia all with the same result. Any thoughts? Anyone running Ubuntu on a this laptop or this card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you install wrong drivers.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime
```

That will install the correct driver. But an attempt to install a driver from `.run` file could spoil everything. It is better to run that file again with `--uninstall` option.